# cakephp, i18n .po files, How to use them correctly

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, poedit

I have finally managed to set up a multilingual cakephp site.
Although not finished it is the first time where I can change the DEFAULT_LANGUAGE in the bootstrap and I can see the language to change.

My problem right now is that I cannot understand very well how to use the po files correctly.
According to the tutorials I've used I need to create a folder /app/locale and inside that folder create a folder for each language in the following format: /locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES.

I have done that and I have also managed to extract a default.pot file using cake i18n extract. And it appears that all occurrences of the __() function have been found succesfully.

In my application I'm using 2 languages: eng and gre.
I can see why you would need a seperate folder for each language.
However in my case nothing happens when I edit the po files inside each folder....well almost nothing. If I edit the /app/locale/**gre**/LC_MESSAGES/default.po I have no language changes. If I edit the /app/locale/**eng**/LC_MESSAGES/default.po then the language changes to the new value (on the translation field) and it does not switch to the other language.

What am I doing wrong.
*I hope I made myself as clear as possible.*

Comment: I think I got it right .... I should not use two folders when I have 2 languages but rather 1. So if my default language is eng then I should have a single folder for the second language gre.

Comment: Here you can find a simple internationalization tutorial using poedit: http://wpy.me/en/blog/5-cakephp-simple-internationalization-tutorial-using-i18n-shell-and-poedit

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to go about it. The easiest is to code the app in the primary language and to just wrap all translatable strings in `__()`. Later you can add `.po` files for each translation you may want.

<strike>The problem with this approach is that if you were to change the text in the original language, you'll also need to change the `msgid` entry for this string in every `.po` file you may have. This can become quite cumbersome if you have to support many different languages.</strike>

Please disregard the old information above. A properly set up i18n workflow will use `xgettext` or similar utilities to automatically extract `__()` wrapped strings from the source code and produce, update and merge .po files. Nothing cumbersome about it.

---

The alternative is to use a "descriptor" text in the source files and put the actual text in `.po` files, even for the primary language. I.e:

```
__('PRODUCT CAPTION');

/eng/.po
msgid "PRODUCT CAPTION"
msgstr "Buy our awesome products!"

/ger/.po
msgid "PRODUCT CAPTION"
msgstr "Kaufen Sie unsere Produkte!"
```

What works better depends on the project and on you, you'll have to figure it out...

Comment: When is it considered to be a "descriptor" text? UPPERCASE?

Comment: @ters That's purely conceptual, "descriptor" is not even an official term AFAIK. I just mean "something that's obviously a placeholder".

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fr');
```

to set the language of the user to french.